# React-Bootstrap: Why renders the Alert component the text differently if the text is stored inside a state variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap that targets Bootstrap v3 and I am using the Alert component to show messages to the user.

Furthermore I need to show messages with multiple lines. For the line break I use <br />.

If I "hard-code" the multiple line text inside the Alert component the component is working as expected showing multiple lines.

But if I use a variable which belongs to the state of the parent component it is not working.

**What is the reason for this behavior?**

```
class MyAlert extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: "Hello <br /> world! <br /> This line ..."
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Alert bsStyle="warning">{this.state.message}</Alert>

        <Alert bsStyle="info">
          "Hello <br /> world! <br /> This line ..."
        </Alert>
      </div>
    );
  }
} //MyAlert
```

Here the output:

[image]

[image: Edit j78lyjkqv9]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second `<Alert>` with bsStyle set to info is rendering it as HTML not a string. Notice that the quotation marks are being displayed. So, it isn't a string. Whereas, `this.state.message` is a string so it is not interpreting the `<br />` as a line break. Hope that makes sense.

Here is a work around.

```
<Alert bsStyle="warning">
  <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.message }}></p>
</Alert>
```

Hope this helps.