# react-bootstrap multi line alert for dynamically set data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert, react-bootstrap

I am using versions:

```
react@16.8.6
react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.8
```

I have an alert whose content is dynamically changing based on what the user is doing with the page:

```
<Alert variant="danger" show={this.state.showDangerAlert}>{this.state.dangerAlertText}</Alert>
```

In some cases, there are multiple messages that need to be displayed.  I am trying to get each message displayed on its own line.  I have tried using new lines and various HTML structures.  The new line is not displayed, but the data is not on a new line either:

[image]

As for the HTML, it is just printed verbatim and not interpreted:

[image]

[I know the alert can interpret the HTML since the online documentation shows it doing it.  Below is an example of a horizontal rule being displayed in the alert:](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts/)

[image]

My problem is that my text is being set dynamically where the example is static.  Any ideas on how to force the alert to display multiple lines when it is set dynamically?

I have reviewed a few different posts with similar problems.  [The closest I have come is this one, but I think they are using different versions since the 'bsStyle' referenced is not documented anywhere that I can find in react-bootstrap.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683071/react-bootstrap-why-renders-the-alert-component-the-text-differently-if-the-tex)

Thanks a lot for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use unique `alert` boxes for each alert message. With that way the user can easily close them one-by-one. If you really want to show all messages inside one alert I suggest you this. Use an array inside your component where you handle the alert.

Let's assume that you store your alert inside an array somewhere, for example:

```
const alerts = ['First line', 'Second line', 'Third line'];
```

Then your component should get those and render them as the follow:

```
const YourOwnComponent = props => {
  const { alerts } = props;

  return (
    <Alert>
      {alerts.map(line => (
        <p>{line}</p>
      ))}
    </Alert>
  );
};
```

With this your alert will look like this:
[image]

After this you can manage your alert as you wish.